# monogame screen resolution is incorrect

Tags: graphics, resolution, monogame

Monogame, or XNA really, is reporting the wrong screen resolution on my Surface Pro 3.

Using GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width and Height returns dimensions of 800 x 600, which is incorrect. So, I cannot set up my game size correctly.

I've been using this code without problem on an Acer V5 and can set the game resolution to a size I expect. This is because the GraphicsAdapter reports the correct screen size.

Whether using it as is, or docking the tablet with an external monitor, returns exactly the same resolution. What error is causing this?

Comment: Please don't use the `xna` tag since Monogame is effectively a fork of XNA and thus different products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to be a bug in Monogame, and was fixed.

If you are not building from the latest source code, it is possible that you still have the bug in your monogame dll.

See:
https://github.com/danzel/MonoGame/commit/0c36642129d89a12b30bcfc7d13256739d5483af

Comment: Okay, I'll check it but I just downloaded MonoGame on my machine today. Maybe the link for the executable is old on the site. I'll get it from github.

Comment: yeah, I am referring to using the source instead of the pre-compiled binaries.  Build the latest dev branch.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much for your quick response.