# MonoGame GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode not working

Tags: c#, fullscreen, monogame

I created a simple test app using MonoGame (version 3.2, last official at the time of writing), but I cannot make the app go fullscreen.

I found this code elsewhere:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height;
    graphics.ApplyChanges();

    Window.IsBorderless = true;
    Window.Position = new Point(0, 0);

    base.Initialize();
}
```

But the problem is that `GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode` is always returning a screen size of `800x600`. Also, the `GraphicsAdapter.Adapters` collection only contains a single adapter, with a single supported display mode (800x600).

What could be the problem here? My current resolution is 1920x1080, and I get the same results if I connect two monitors as an extended desktop (which is my usual setup).

**Update**

At the end I simply added a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and used:

```
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

I still wonder why MonoGame doesn't detect any adapters/screens properly.

**Update 2** The issue was fixed in a non-official build (at the time of writing), as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221553/1488067).

Comment: Try moving that code to the end of your `Game` constructor

Comment: @Vlad: that won't work because `GraphicsDevice` is null inside the ctor (at least in MonoGame, I think this behaves differently in XNA).

Comment: I've just set `graphics.IsFullScreen = true` and *nothing* else after `base.Initialize()` and it works as expected. You're using winforms to solve this, so I can guess you're using Windows, and not Linux/Mac. Do you mind confirming which version? I'll set up a VM and have a look

Comment: @Joe: thanks! Yes, it's Windows 8.1 (64 bit, if that matters). Hmmm, also, now I've found the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26220345/1488067). I'll check this and if it works, I'll vote as duplicate.

Comment: @LousyCoder that's what I was running this under. It's just going to be a debugging task I think, eliminating potential causes (something we can't do for you)

Comment: @Joe: ok, building the latest develop branch solved the problem. The [commit linked in the other answer](https://github.com/danzel/MonoGame/commit/0c36642129d89a12b30bcfc7d13256739d5483af) fixes the issue in `GraphicsAdapter`, voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `graphics` code to after the `base.Initialize` call - this is because the system hasn't initialized, and initializes to some default settings. Typically, we would *want* to be able to change the graphics during the course of the game (ie after initialization), in case the User changes any settings in-game.

Comment: Didn't help. In fact, `GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode` is 800x600 even in `Update` and `Draw` methods. It stays at 800x600 all time, even if I hardcode `graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth` and `Height` to a different resolution.